# PHP mysqli_query Syntax Error in insert

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert data into a MySQL table using PHP.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $het = $_GET['het'];

    header('Content-Type: application/json; Charset=UTF-8');
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost:8889","root","root","imreigye_wp") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
    mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8mb4');

    //This SQL string is really long
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `rendelesiidok`(`Ev`, `Het`, `Nap`, `BattaR`, `BattaT`, `HacsekR`, `HacsekT`, `MolnarR`, `MolnarT`, `Pentek`) VALUES ('2016','" . $het . "','1','','','','','','',''); INSERT INTO `rendelesiidok`(`Ev`, `Het`, `Nap`, `BattaR`, `BattaT`, `HacsekR`, `HacsekT`, `MolnarR`, `MolnarT`, `Pentek`) VALUES ('2016','" . $het . "','2','','','','','','',''); INSERT INTO `rendelesiidok`(`Ev`, `Het`, `Nap`, `BattaR`, `BattaT`, `HacsekR`, `HacsekT`, `MolnarR`, `MolnarT`, `Pentek`) VALUES ('2016','" . $het . "','3','','','','','','',''); INSERT INTO `rendelesiidok`(`Ev`, `Het`, `Nap`, `BattaR`, `BattaT`, `HacsekR`, `HacsekT`, `MolnarR`, `MolnarT`, `Pentek`) VALUES ('2016','" . $het . "','4','','','','','','',''); INSERT INTO `rendelesiidok`(`Ev`, `Het`, `Nap`, `BattaR`, `BattaT`, `HacsekR`, `HacsekT`, `MolnarR`, `MolnarT`, `Pentek`) VALUES ('2016','" . $het . "','5','','','','','','','');";
    mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("ERROR: " . mysqli_error($connection));
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

When I run my code I get a MySQL error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `rendelesiidok`(`Ev`, `Het`, `Nap`, `BattaR`, `BattaT`, `HacsekR`, `' at line 1
>   However, my MySQL query runs with no problem if I run it trough phpMyAdmin.
>   Here is my MySQL log:

```
160401 23:07:22    15 Connect   root@localhost on imreigye_wp
           15 Query SET NAMES utf8mb4
           15 Query INSERT INTO `rendelesiidok`(`Ev`, `Het`, `Nap`, `BattaR`, `BattaT`, `HacsekR`, `HacsekT`, `MolnarR`, `MolnarT`, `Pentek`) VALUES ('2016','14','1','','','','','','',''); INSERT INTO `rendelesiidok`(`Ev`, `Het`, `Nap`, `BattaR`, `BattaT`, `HacsekR`, `HacsekT`, `MolnarR`, `MolnarT`, `Pentek`) VALUES ('2016','14','2','','','','','','',''); INSERT INTO `rendelesiidok`(`Ev`, `Het`, `Nap`, `BattaR`, `BattaT`, `HacsekR`, `HacsekT`, `MolnarR`, `MolnarT`, `Pentek`) VALUES ('2016','14','3','','','','','','',''); INSERT INTO `rendelesiidok`(`Ev`, `Het`, `Nap`, `BattaR`, `BattaT`, `HacsekR`, `HacsekT`, `MolnarR`, `MolnarT`, `Pentek`) VALUES ('2016','14','4','','','','','','',''); INSERT INTO `rendelesiidok`(`Ev`, `Het`, `Nap`, `BattaR`, `BattaT`, `HacsekR`, `HacsekT`, `MolnarR`, `MolnarT`, `Pentek`) VALUES ('2016','14','5','','','','','','','')
           15 Quit
```

NOTE: I already tried using simple quotes instead of the special ones. That didn't help.

Comment: put each sql query into seperate variables to segment your code better and to make it easier to read. Also it could be due to the ` symbole being input on the names of your table and fields

Comment: Back ticks are perfectly acceptable in MySQL (and other SQL environments) @Juakali92

Comment: @JayBlanchard fair enough, didn't realise you could

Comment: Actually you *should* use them all of the time if you wanted to prevent problems with possible keywords used as table/column names, etc. Using any single or double quote around table/column names will cause the query to fail.

Comment: You can only execute one query per `mysqli_query`. This is open to SQL injections. Instead of `''` you should redefine your table and set up default NULL values, then you won't need to pass in these values.

Comment: You should be using [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) *or* use multiple value sets in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `mysqli_query()` supports multiple queries. What you want to do can be written in 1 query like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `rendelesiidok`(`Ev`, `Het`, `Nap`, `BattaR`, `BattaT`, `HacsekR`, `HacsekT`, `MolnarR`, `MolnarT`, `Pentek`) 
VALUES ('2016','" . $het . "','1','','','','','','',''),
('2016','" . $het . "','2','','','','','','',''), 
('2016','" . $het . "','3','','','','','','',''), 
('2016','" . $het . "','4','','','','','','',''), 
('2016','" . $het . "','5','','','','','','','')";
```

For more info visit [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)